# How to find specific lines in a table using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-testing, automated-tests, gui-testing

Here is an example code:

```
<div id="productOrderContainer">
  <table class="table gradient myPage">
```

So this table being in productOrderContainer has several columns and depending on several things will have several rows which all have several columns. An example is:

What I want to do is to for example get the first row of this table. ( rows have id's such as: `<td rowspan="1">` ) And then again for example in this rowspan look for a specific value in a specific `<div>`

So in psudo-code what I want to say is:

Get me the table, get me the n'th row, get me the value in `<div id='something'>`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you can try following

```java
int index = 0;
WebElement baseTable = driver.findElement(By.className("table gradient myPage"));
List<WebElement> tableRows = baseTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
tableRows.get(index).getText();
```

You can also iterate over tablerows to perform any function you want.

Comment: That doesn't look right at all.  `WebDriver.findElement(By.className(""))` will locate *every* element in the document, not the table the OP is looking for.  So the next line will collect all the `<TR>`s in the entire document, not in the specific table.

Comment: My Mistake... the By.className wasn't supposed to be empty. copy paste  error. Thanks @RossPatterson

Comment: @KorayTugay if the solution did not work for please let me know with more info. I will be glad to help.

Answer (score 5):

You want:

```
int rowNumber=...;
string value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='productOrderContainer']/table/tbody/tr[" + rowNumber +"]/div[id='something']")).getText();
```

In other words, locate `<DIV>` with the id "something" contained within the `rowNumber`th `<TR>` of the `<TABLE>` contained within the `<DIV>` with the id "productOrderContainer", and then get its text value (which is what I believe you mean by "get me the value in `<div id='something'>`"

Answer (score 2):

Well previously, I used the approach that you can find inside the `WebElement`:

```
WebElement baseTable = driver.findElement(By.tagName("table"));
WebElement tableRow = baseTable.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[2]")); //should be the third row
webElement cellIneed = tableRow.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]"));
String valueIneed = cellIneed.getText();
```

Please note that I find inside the found `WebElement` instance.

The above is Java code, assuming that `driver` variable is healthy instance of `WebDriver`

Comment: That won't work as written because `WebElement.findElement(By.xpath(...))` interprets the XPath locator in the document context, not in the element context like every other `By.whatever()`.

Comment: It needs to be `tableRow.findElement(By.xpath("td[2]"))`, right?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to access table cell

```
WebElement thirdCell = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]"));
```

If you want to access nested table cell -

```
WebElement thirdCell = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"+//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]));
```

For more details visit this [Tutorial](http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/10/access-web-elements-inside-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
(.//*[table-locator])[n]
```

where `n` represents the specific line.

Answer (score 0):

The following code allows you to specify the row/column number and get the resulting **cell value**:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebElement base = driver.findElement(By.className("Table"));
tableRows = base.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
List<WebElement> tableCols = tableRows.get([ROW_NUM]).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
String cellValue = tableCols.get([COL_NUM]).getText();
```