# WebDriver Selenium: Need to select element in the table after some element

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

The `HTML` page contains a table of users details.
I need to remove user.
I can select the first element in the row by username.
I need to select the "Delete" button on that row to delete that user.
The `HTML` structure is:

```
<table id="tblUsersGrid" cellpadding="2">  
<thead>  
<tbody>
<tr class="aboutMeRow" data-parentid="223">  
<tr>  
<tr>  
 ...
<tr>
    <td class="cell cell_278 cell_NameCell">xoxo</td>
    <td class="optionIcon overrideFloat orgIcon cell cell_278 gridCell"></td>  
    <td class="cell cell_278 gridCell">Custom</td>  
    <td class="cell cell_278 gridCell">qaadmin</td>  
    <td class="cell cell_278 gridCell">0</td>  
    <td class="cell gridCell">  
        <div class="removeAccountIcon"></div>  
    <td class="cell gridCell">  
        <div class="editAccountIcon"></div>  
    </td>  
    <td></td>  
</tr>
```

So I can easily select the desired row by

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='cell_NameCell'][contains(text(),'xoxo')]"))
```

But how can I reach the `removeAccountIcon` element on that row?
I saw many questions dealing with selecting elements inside tables but didn't find solution for this issue.
Is there a way to do this by `CSS` selector, not only by `Xpath`? (I am sure there is a `Xpath` solution for this).

Comment: I know it isn't what you really want but you could find the table then iterate per row and use findElements to get the list of columns (td). Over the list you can get elements by index to check the user and get the button (here is a similar code to do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14192252)

Comment: Well, this is a solution. You are right. But I guess there is a single expression (Xpath) to do this work.

Comment: Yep, I guess too... something like this: //td[contains(text(),'xoxo')/following-sibling::td//div[@class='removeAccountIcon']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath axes `preceding-sibling` would helps you to resolve the issue. You can try below xpath:

`//td[preceding-sibling::td[contains(text(),'xoxo')]][5]/div[@class='removeAccountIcon']`

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it in one go using the following `XPath` expression:

```
//tr[td[contains(@class, 'cell_NameCell')] = 'xoxo']//div[@class='removeAccountIcon']
```

Here we are locating the appropriate `tr` row by checking the text of the `td` element containing `cell_NameCell` class (this is your username cell). Then, we locate the "Remove Account Icon" inside this row.

Comment: I understand your logic but the Xpath expression you provided didn't work for me. I tried to edit it but still couldn't succeed making it working.

Comment: Could you please review the expression you wrote so it will work? I already have working solution provided by @Abhishek but it will be very nice to have more than 1 way to do this.

Comment: @Eliyahu yup, fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, but this expression is still not good. Just by copying it into the 'driver.findElement(By.xpath("****")).click();'  as an expression instead of the asterisks Eclipse editor detecting syntax errors...

Comment: @Eliyahu alright, have you managed the single and double quotes correctly?

Comment: I copy-pasted it as-is but it looks to be wrong. I don't know this expression rules. Normally I use [@class='calssname'][contains(text(), 'theText']

Comment: @Eliyahu the expression should work, I've tested it. Recheck the quotes. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83136/discussion-between-eliyahu-and-alecxe).

Answer (score 1):

If you can select the correct row, you can select the desired element within that row by calling findElement on that row instead of the original driver. However, the code you suggested for finding the correct row doesn't appear to work. (It selects a td instead of a tr.)

I would suggest the following:

```
WebElement userDataInRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//td[contains(text(),'xoxo')]))
WebElement row = userDataInRow.findElement(By.xpath(".."))
row.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='removeAccountIcon']"))
```

The second line goes to the parent element of the selected td element.

Comment: I have a table. Each row contains `class="removeAccountIcon"` element. I need to select this element on desired row, containing the user I want to delete, not the first user in the table.

Comment: This is not the way I asked for, but thank you. It's interesting approach too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an option to find the parent by using the css selectors. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) article gives other alternates for finding the same.

To capture the "Remove" button by using the xpath, we just need to traverse back to the parent of the "Name" cell of the table and then fetch the "div" of the "remove link/button".

Then your xpath `//td[@class='cell'][contains(text(),'xoxo')]` should be updated as below :

`//td[contains(text(),'xoxo')]/../td/div[@class='removeAccountIcon']`

This will capture the "Remove Account Icon" based on the given name.

Comment: I will check this tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please review the expression you wrote so it will work? I already have working solution provided by @Abhishek but it will be very nice to have more than 1 way to do this.

Comment: My Bad... there is a syntax error.. I didnt validte the xpath mentioned in the question. Anyways.. Here is the way to get it..